# How to wait for promise to complete with returned value using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I’m having an issue with my project. In my angularjs controller a function is being executed and then my function to make a call to my database to update a record is executing without waiting for the first function to complete and therefore sending over an undefined `result` variable.

Below you can find my code snippets with my attempts so far.

**Submit button function:**

```
$scope.submitNewStarters = function () {

    // result is returning as undefined <<<<< Issue
    var result = $scope.sendNewStarterDetailsToApi();

    $scope.updateArchivedImportFlag(result); 

};
```

**Controller function handling the logic:**

```
$scope.sendNewStarterDetailsToApi = function () {

swal({
    title: "Confirmation",
    text: "Are you sure you want to import the new starter details?",
    icon: "info",
    dangerMode: true,
    buttons: ["No", "Yes"]
}).then(function (approve) {

    if (approve) {

        // Get each of the new starter details that have been set to true for import.
        var newStartsToImport = $scope.tableParams.data.filter(x => x.imported == true);

        for (let i = 0; i < newStartsToImport.length; i++) {

            // Parses the current new starter object into a stringified object to be sent to the api.
            $scope.newStartsToImport = $scope.createApiObject(newStartsToImport[i]);

            // A check to ensure that nothing has went wrong and that the stringify object has worked.
            if ($scope.newStartsToImport !== "") {

                apiFactory.postNewStarterDetailsToApi($scope.newStartsToImport).then(function (response) {

                    var isSuccessful = response.data.d.WasSuccessful;

                    if (isSuccessful)
                        toastr.success("New starter details successfully sent to API.", "Success!");
                    else {
                        var errorMessage = response.data.d.ErrorMessage;
                        toastr.error("New starter details were unsuccessfully sent to API. Please try again. \n" + errorMessage, "Error!");
                    }

                });
            }
            else {
                toastr("An error has occurred when attempting to create the data object to be sent to API. The process has stopped!", "Error!");
                break;
            }
        }

        return newStartsToImport;
    }
    else
        toastr.info("No new starter details were sent to API", "Information!");
    });
};
```

**Factory function for API call:**

```
postNewStarterDetailsToApi: function (data) {
    return $http({
        url: "https://www.example.com/services/service.svc/Import",
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        }
    }).then(function successCallbwack(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
        return response;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        console.log('An error has occured during the function call postNewStarterDetailsToApi(): ', response);
    });
}
```

So with the concept of promises how am I able to execute the `sendNewStarterDetailsToApi` function, wait for it to complete and then return the populated array? Once the populated array (`result`) is returned then execute the `updateArchivedImportFlag` function.

**Below I've added an illustration of what I'd like to achieve:**

[image: For loop logic]

Comment: i suggest you to make a single request with the updated elements, making asynchronous requests on a loop wont work as the loop will continue to execute and wont wait for then

Comment: I appreciate the quick and kind comeback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I am using is , save all the promises in an array .
Use any promise library or es6 Promise, and use .all function to wait for all promises to execute

The syntax i wrote is not totally correct. Since you are using angular js , you can use $q.all

```js
$scope.sendNewStarterDetailsToApi = function () {

    swal({
        title: "Confirmation",
        text: "Are you sure you want to import the new starter details?",
        icon: "info",
        dangerMode: true,
        buttons: ["No", "Yes"]
    }).then(function (approve) {
        var res = [];
        if (approve) {
    
            // Get each of the new starter details that have been set to true for import.
            var newStartsToImport = $scope.tableParams.data.filter(x => x.imported == true);
    
            for (let i = 0; i < newStartsToImport.length; i++) {
    
                // Parses the current new starter object into a stringified object to be sent to the api.
                $scope.newStartsToImport = $scope.createApiObject(newStartsToImport[i]);
    
                // A check to ensure that nothing has went wrong and that the stringify object has worked.
                if ($scope.newStartsToImport !== "") {
                    res.push(apiFactory.postNewStarterDetailsToApi($scope.newStartsToImport))
                }
                else {
                    toastr("An error has occurred when attempting to create the data object to be sent to API. The process has stopped!", "Error!");
                    break;
                }
            }
    
            return Promise.all(res);
        }
        else
            toastr.info("No new starter details were sent to API", "Information!");
        }).then(function (data) {
            data.forEach((response) => {
                var isSuccessful = response.data.d.WasSuccessful;

                if (isSuccessful)
                    toastr.success("New starter details successfully sent to API.", "Success!");
                else {
                    var errorMessage = response.data.d.ErrorMessage;
                    toastr.error("New starter details were unsuccessfully sent to API. Please try again. \n" + errorMessage, "Error!");
                }
            })
        }).then((res) => {
            //call Submit new starters
        })
    };
```

Comment: Your solution appears to work for me however there's one last outstanding bit that I can't seem to resolve. The last promise `.then((res) => {`. `res` is coming through as undefined. How could I use the `res` variable to contain an array of the results sent to the api successfully?

Comment: Yes. res is undefined since we did not return anything from previous then. Just return what you want in previous then and you can access it

Comment: thanks for that explanation. Your proposed solution has resolved my issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's hard to see that this answer solves the problem given that `$scope.sendNewStarterDetailsToApi()` still returns undefined. It should return Promise and `$scope.submitNewStarters()` should be rewritten accordingly.